# How to remove iframe's scrollbars?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, cross-browser

How to remove iframe's scrllbars? In Firefox it's easy, however I found myself unable to achieve this effect to be compatible with all major browsers.

Comment: See this Q&A for answer & explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470015/html5-iframe-no-scrolling

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### CSS

```
iframe {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

And/or use [Coin_op's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4460952/31671), it seems to be better.

Comment: But if you check in IE compatibility mode it comes back, so you have to add scrolling:'no' to the iframe it self.this link explains it. http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?26750-Iframe-without-scrollbar

Answer (score 42):

If the CSS technique isn't working for you, try also adding the property `scrolling="no"` to the `iframe` HTML tag.

```html
<iframe scrolling="no" src="..." >
```

Comment: And this gentlemen, is how I finally got the animated gifs to keep animating, even with a postback call from IE.  Attaching extra code didn't work, delaying source load didn't work, but the ancient element iFrame did the trick. Once I dropped the scroll bars, it was as good as gold!

Answer (score 5):

on top of Alex's answer, I also had to add the following to remove horizontal toolbars from both FF and Chrome. This was added in the i-frame page, even though it should be possible to add it in the css as well:

```
    <style>
        iframe::-webkit-scrollbar {  
        display: none;
    }  
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe runat="server" id="_theFrame"  src="url" width="100%" scrolling="no" height="200" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="display: block; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent; width: 100%;" />
```