# How to hide scrollbar in iframe using css?

Tags: css, html

I use HTML5.In my *iframe* , if I use *scrolling="no"* my browser(chrome) supports it.But some  sites says that *scrolling* attribute is not supported in HTML5.And I decided to use css but *overflow : hidden; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden* any of it does not effect anything.What should I do? Should I continue to use *scrolling="no"* becuse it is still usable in HTML5

Comment: Are you applying the `overflow:hidden` style in the parent page or in the child page?

Comment: in the page where I use *iframe* tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove iframe's scrollbars?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460844/how-to-remove-iframes-scrollbars)

Comment: @MaksatYalkabov see my Q&A for solution&explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470015/html5-iframe-no-scrolling

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
<style>
    .restricted{width:200px; height:200px; overflow-y: hidden;}
</style>
```

iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://cnn.com" class="restricted" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

To hide the scrollbars, you will need to add a scrolling attribute to the iframe.

```
<iframe id="myiframe" src="http://www.cnn.com" style="width:200px;height:200px;" scrolling="no"/>
```

Comment: but I want to do that using css

Comment: scrolling attr is not supported in html5

Comment: but still you can use it